# Spivak Calculus ed.3 chapter 3 problem 27 (a)

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, self-learning

The question is:
a) Suppose f (x)= x + 1. Are there any functions g such that f $\circ$ g = g $\circ$ f?

Then the answer provided states:
The condition f $\circ$ g = g $\circ$ f means that g(x) + 1 = g(x + 1) for all x. There are many such g. In fact, g can be defined arbitrarily for 0$\leq$x$<$1, and its values for other x determined from this equation.

I understand the first part of the answer, it is obvious that  g(x) + 1 = g(x + 1). I don't understand however why the interval 0$\leq$x$<$1 is special versus any other interval. Also, what are these many such functions?  I would appreciate any help with this, as I am using the textbook to self-study.

Comment: Because once you specify it on that interval that dictates its entire behavior by the functional equation.

Comment: @Randall's comment and dxiv's answer explain it all. As to a simple specific example, look at g(x)=x+a for any a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand however why the interval 0$\leq$x$<$1 is special versus any other interval

Because of this $\color{red}1$ in $\,g(x+\color{red}1)=g(x)+1\,$ which, after repeated application, gives: $$g(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + g\left(\{x\}\right)$$

In other words, the values of $g\left(\{x\}\right)$ univocally define $g(x)$ on the entire real axis. But the fractional part $\{x\} \in [0,1)\,$, so it is enough to define $g$ on $[0,1)$.

For a trivial example, you can define $g$ to be identically $0$ on $[0,1)$, which then gives $g(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor\,$, which obviously satisfies $g(x+1)=g(x)+1\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   On a second reading and depending on where the accent lies, the question could also be interpreted as why $[0,1)$ is "*special*" versus some other interval of length $1$, for example $[13,14)\,$.

The answer to that is that $[0,1)$ is not special in that sense. $g$ could be arbitrarily defined on *any* interval $[a, a+1)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}\,$, then extended to the entire $\mathbb{R}$ using the same idea as above.

Comment: @Bernalillo This is a pretty basic explanation. Fractional part or floor is not some fancy function.

Comment: @Bernalillo If $x \in [n,n+1)$ then $g(x)=g(x-1)+1=g(x-2)+2=\dots=g(x-n)+n\,$ and $x-n \in [0,1)$. That said, I would expect the floor function to be covered somewhere in pre-calculus algebra i.e. prior to Spivak, and the fractional part is simply $\,x - \lfloor x \rfloor\,$ on $\,\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: I understand. So any g(x) can be shown as g(x-n)+n, where  x−n∈[0,1), n is the floor and x-n is the fraction. For example g(5.5)=g(.5)+5. In other words, all we have to define is the fraction. And if we define the fraction to be uniform 0, then g(5.5)=0+5=5, which of course equals g(4.5)+1, which is 0+4+1=5; and in the general case ⌊x⌋+1= ⌊x+1⌋ (which probably also requires some fancy proof but I think intuitively makes sense). I could not have done this remotely without you.

Comment: @Bernalillo Right, that's the gist of it. Glad you worked it out.